# Email safe tables for receipt view with dots between items

Tags: html, email, tailwind-css, html-email

Trying to build a receipt type view in html/css for emails... I can easily solve this issue w/ flex, but many mail clients don't support it.  I want it to look like this, where the center column expands based on the content in the left and right side columns and fills with dots.

[image]

I am using tables because usually they're the most safe for use in emails.  Open to other suggestions though.  Is this possible?

```
<table
  class="w-full border-collapse border border-release-blue-400 table-auto"
>
  <tbody class="w-full">
    <tr class="w-full border border-slate-700">
      <td align="left" class="pt-6 w-1/4">
        <span class="text-black text-sm">
          Repayment Amount
        </span>
      </td>

      <td
        align="center"
        class="border border-b-2 border-dotted border-b-gray-200"
      ></td>
      <td align="right" class="pt-6 w-1/6">
        <span class="text-black text-sm">
          $775.13
        </span>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Should be possible - but please first post your CSS inlined. We can't tell what the classes are, and some email clients can't either (they delete style blocks and externally linked CSS).

Comment: How does design should look like if you have second row where first column is tighter than "Repayment Amount" (for example "Total")? Does the dots should be close to text in any row (if so it can not be done using tables I guess)? Or there should be "invisible" column like structure where dots are starting from the widest row column?

Comment: FWIW, the default flex *is* supported reasonably well (https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-display-flex/), but if you need anything like align-items or justify-content, these have very poor support. So send through an example with that, if you want us to look at it and suggest a fallback.